# Loop through dynamic controls in placeholder

Tags: c#

I have 4 radiobuttonlist in page that are added dynamically in placeholder. I have to check which option is selected in radiobuttonlist in codebehind .All controls are added inside panel in placeholder.Html is as follows:

```
table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="rb1" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="1" /><label>excellent</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="2" /><label>good</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="3" /><label>average</label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="4" /><label>not relevant</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it `asp.net`?

Comment: _"placeholder.Html is as follows"_ Is that the rendered HTML? Then better show the aspx code with the `RadioButtonList`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an aspx page, try iterating through the controls of your panel like:

```
foreach(var control in yourPanel.Controls)
{ 
   try
   { 
      var radioButtonList = (RadioButtonList)control; 

      foreach(var item in radioButtonList.Items)
      {
         // something like 
         var selected = item.Selected;
         // or whatever code fits your needs
      }
   }
   catch
   {
     continue;
   }
}
```